# jQuery show only one div when I hover another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few similar blocks with this structure.

My "info_hover" block is hidden until I'll hover "item_name" block. But when I hover it, all "info_hover" blocks displayed. How to make "info_hover" block displayed only at that div what I have hovered.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="item_image">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="info_hover">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt, sapiente! ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item_info">
    <div class="item_name">item_name</div>
    <div class="item_price">item_price</div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$( ".item_name" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( ".info_hover" ).show();
  }, function() {
    $( ".info_hover" ).hide();
  }
);
```

http://codepen.io/Vlasov/pen/apgmxy?editors=1010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
   $( ".item_name" ).hover(
      function() {
        $(this).closest(".item_block").find(".info_hover").show();
      }, function() {
        $(this).closest(".item_block").find(".info_hover").hide();
      }
    );
```

You reference `this`, because you want to access an element relative to the hovered element. Then you find a parent element that holds both `this` element and the element you want to access. In this case, `.item_block` is a logical choice as the top parent of the individual item. After that, you find the element you want to access within the parent. Lastly, you modify the element as you wish.